# What's the Copyright status of Tux The Penguin (The Linux Mascot)?

Tags: permissions, games

Hi my question is about Tux The Penguin, and I'm just wondering, would I be able to use Tux The Penguin in a project if I wanted to and release it to the public?

I don't know what kind of license Tux actually has.

If this isn't the appropriate place to ask this question could someone please point me to the proper place. Since Tux is pretty much seen as the universal mascot for Linux (At least that's how I see it) I figured it also relates some form to Ubuntu. Like if I wanted to make a video game would I need permission to use him? Would I need permission if I planned selling it? All these questions and more lol.

Comment: This isn't really about Ubuntu (and in a default install, I don't think Tux appears at any point in the interface), and is a legal question (so you should be asking your legal counsel for legal advice).

Comment: I've used this image https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tux.svg. The license allows it to use in a project. Just add proper attribute to the author.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [http://isc.tamu.edu/~lewing/linux/](https://web.archive.org/web/20191001080512/https://isc.tamu.edu/~lewing/linux/) for details.

Tux the Penguin is [an image created by Larry Ewing](https://www.linuxmark.org/), and is not owned by The Linux Foundation.

Comment: link  http://isc.tamu.edu/~lewing/linux/ is dead

Comment: First link does not seem to be working, not from here or foundation page.  error is isc.tamu.edu sent an invalid response.

ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT  There is a email link to Larry Ewing on second link.

Comment: Substituted a link from earlier this month for the original link through http://archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20191001080512/https://isc.tamu.edu/~lewing/linux/